# ASP.Net: Upload of a video, create Thumbnail

Tags: asp.net, video, thumbnails, image

in my asp.net page user can upload a video.
On the upload-page there should be no video-player, instead there should be a picture of the video, like a thumbnail.

So how to create a thumbnail / picture of a uploaded video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link on SO that seems to answer the question: [How do I get a Video Thumbnail in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155314/how-do-i-get-a-video-thumbnail-in-net)