# Thumbnail library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, thumbnails

I'm looking for a thumbnail library for .NET. I don't care if free or paid. I would like to generate thumbnails for file preview, supporting as many file types as possible:

```
images, videos, pfd, office docs, ...
```

Could someone recommend any?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I don't think there's a one stop shop for what you want. Instead you'll need to use a series of libraries to achieve the result:

- **PDF:** Previously I've used [PDF Sharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) which is pretty good for free.
- **Video:** From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155314/how-do-i-get-a-video-thumbnail-in-net) there's http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx

Alternatively you could try a [more general approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api) (Although I've not used this myself)