# how can i show image thumbnail of avideo in listview control in vb?

Tags: vb.net, image, listview

I am writing a simple windows based application show split a video and show the thumbnails in listview .

I found this code, but from here I need thumbnails instead of icons

```
Dim strFileSize As String = " "
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(SPath & "\" & FolderName)
Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.*")
Dim fi As IO.FileInfo
For Each fi In aryFi
 Dim ico As Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fi.FullName)
  ImageList1.Images.Add(ico)
  ListView1.Items.Add(fi.ToString, ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
Next
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155314/how-do-i-get-a-video-thumbnail-in-net

Comment: i am using the ffmpeg....to split the video.....the main problem is to show it in listview

Comment: Use ffmpeg to grab a still from 5 or 10 secs into the clip, perhaps make a thumbnail of that image, add to your Imagelist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to take the thumbnails from each video in ffmpeg and start the process. my option is

```
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "ffmpeg.exe")
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
 proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
 proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
 For Each fi In aryFi
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + fi.FullName + " -vframes 1 " & (SPath & "\" & FolderName1 & "\") & fi.Name & "%d.jpg"
        proc.Start()
 Next
```

add the image in image list and show it

```
For Each files In filesList
ImageList1.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile(files))
Next
```